# How to select customers that didn't place an order in the last 7 days

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to find out the customers that didn't place an order in the last seven days. Basically I have 3 tables: customers, orders and help_desk_agents.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get this information.

The SQL bellow retrieves the customers info, the help desk agent 111 and the last date of the orders of each customer:

```
SELECT DISTINCT customers.customer_id, 
                customers.customer_name, 
                agents.help_desk_agent, 
                Max(orders.order_date) 
FROM   customers 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT customers.customer_id, 
                                  orders.order_date 
                  FROM   orders 
                  GROUP  BY 1, 
                            2) orders2 
              ON customers.customer_id = orders2.customer_id 
       LEFT JOIN help_desk_agents 
              ON customers.help_desk_agent_id = 
                 help_desk_agents.help_desk_agent_id 
WHERE  customer.help_desk_agent_id = 111 
GROUP  BY 1, 
          2, 
          3
```

I would like like somehow to filter the  customers that didn't place an order in the last seven days.

Comment: Can you show us your table structure/s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this at the and of your query :

```
having max(orders.order_date) < dateadd(day, -7, getdate())
```

Comment: Hi Dragan, I got the expected result. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You can try a

```
Datediff(dd,<datecolumn>,getdate())
```

and use

```
>= 7
```

as a condition.

Comment: While this would certainly work, it would execute the `Datediff` function on every single row (of the grouped result). Dragan's answer only executes `dateadd` once for every row.

Comment: Performance wise I agree. My bad. Thanks for the tip for myself!

Answer (score 0):

The query that you want should look like this:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, a.help_desk_agent, 
                Max(orders.order_date) 
FROM customers c JOIN
     (SELECT o.customer_id, MAX(o.order_date) as max_order_date
      FROM orders o
      GROUP BY o.customer_id
     ) o 
     ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id 
WHERE c.help_desk_agent_id = 111 AND
      o.max_order_date < dateadd(day, -7, getdate());
```

Your query has multiple issues:

- The alias `customers.customer_id` is not understood in the subquery.
- The `select distinct` is unnecessary.
- `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary because presumably customers have at least one order and you require a match to the agent table.
- You don't need the agent table, because the information you want is in the `customer` table.